# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uncaught-exception

I've got a problem with my iOS app. I've built my app with storyboard and some code. Initially, i've had a TableView which display some content in the first tab. Now i would like to put this content in another tab, but when i edit my storyboard i get this error :

```
2013-11-28 17:31:17.354 devis_centrage[13961:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173a5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bd8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x016ee9c2 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x017b9608 -[NSArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:] + 40
    4   devis_centrage                      0x000022f8 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 936
    5   UIKit                               0x00225355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    6   UIKit                               0x00225b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
    7   UIKit                               0x0022a3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    8   UIKit                               0x0023e87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    9   UIKit                               0x0023ede9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    10  UIKit                               0x0022c025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x036e12f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x036e0e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x016b5d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x016b5a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x016e077c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016dfac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016df8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    18  UIKit                               0x00229add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    19  UIKit                               0x0022bd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  devis_centrage                      0x00002ccd main + 141
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7870d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here the code for the array initialization :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _aircraft = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

    Aircraft *aircraft = [[Aircraft alloc] init];
    aircraft.name = @"Robin DR400";
    aircraft.immat = @"F-HAZA";
    [_aircraft addObject:aircraft];

    aircraft = [[Aircraft alloc] init];
    aircraft.name = @"Tecnam P2002 JF";
    aircraft.immat= @"F-HAZB";
    [_aircraft addObject:aircraft];

    aircraft = [[Aircraft alloc] init];
    aircraft.name = @"Tecnam P2002 JF";
    aircraft.immat= @"F-HAZC";
    [_aircraft addObject:aircraft];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarController viewControllers][0];
    AircraftViewController *aircraftViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
    aircraftViewController.aircraft = _aircraft;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: One of the arrays you try to access in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is empty

Comment: Have you allocate and initialise your array? Can you post the code where you create array and where you adding item to it?

Comment: Symbolicate the crash report and it will show you the exact line in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method that is causing the problem with the bad array access.

Comment: I've edit the post and add the code for the array initialization, thanks !

Comment: The error indicates you access index `1` but the code you posted makes no reference to index `1`, just `0`. Again, symbolicate the crash report so you know exactly which line of code is causing the problem.

Comment: I suspect that that error did not come from that version of the code.

Comment: Where do you get this error from? Can you comment this line: AircraftViewController *aircraftViewController =... if the app still crashes comment another line: UINavigationController *navigationController =... let me know is it still crash or it stops and when?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will test that. I think you're right about the access index.How do you make a "symbolicate crash report" ?

Comment: @Greg if i comment "AircraftViewController *aircraftViewController =..." app doesn't crash anymore ! But i lost all the content that i have add in the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing second object in an array. If you try to access it then you it(object) to be in your array. Maybe you forgot to init it.

Comment: The array is not empty. It has one object. That is why the valid range is 0 to 0.